# the part of code before and after await task is executed in same thread

Tags: c#, async-await, console

i have the following code in my Console Application Project :

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, main");
    var list = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        list.Add(GetValueAsync(i, i, i));
        //list.Add(GetValueAsync());
    }

    var whenAll = Task.WhenAll(list);
    whenAll.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(@"End program");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


private static async Task<int> GetValueAsync(int val, int delay, int taskId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, task{taskId} sleep");

    await Task.Delay(1000 * delay);

    Console.WriteLine($@"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, task{taskId} awake");
    return val;
}

private static int index = 0;
private static async Task<int> GetValueAsync()
{
    index++;
    Console.WriteLine($@"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, task{index} sleep");

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    Console.WriteLine($@"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, task{index} awake");
    return 10;
}
```

when i use GetValueAsync **with parameters** i get this one :

[image]

when i use GetValueAsync **without parameters** i get this one :

[image]

Why do the part of code after  `await Task.Delay(1000 * delay)` is executed in the same thread ,  when i use `GetValueAsync(int val, int delay, int taskId)`? if i am not wrong , the part after await supposed to be executed in the new thread... (current project is a console application , the main thread is not GUI thread )

Comment: Tasks are executed on the thread pool, when a thread managing a thread pool entry has completed it is returned to the pool. My guess is that in the first example the tasks complete their "second part" so quickly that the same thread is available to service the next request as well.

Comment: May I ask why it is important that separate, new, threads are used for this? Does it matter?

Comment: Multi threading means that your program runs parallel on multiple threads. Nothing more, nothing less.

Async programming means in lay terms that instead of blocking and wait for a call (most likely IO operations) you just register a callback and you will be notified when the underlying operation has finished.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen there is delay in 1 , 2 and 3 seconds respectively

Comment: Yes, which is why it makes sense that the thread is available, the first task has a whole second to complete and let the thread return to the thread pool before the next task requires a thread.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i have shorted  delay , made it 1 millisecond , same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are always hard questions to answer as the answers never seem satisfying to people new to the topic

If you change your code to the following. you will get the expected results

```
list.Add(GetValueAsync(i, 1, i));
```

**Output**

```
1, main
1, task1 sleep
1, task2 sleep
1, task3 sleep
5, task2 awake
4, task3 awake
6, task1 awake
End program
```

So whats wrong with the first results? Simply, more threads are needed, the callbacks happen sufficiently delayed to reuse the same thread. The *Task Scheduler* sees no need to allocate any more (or different) resources for you

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write but longer :) My version→ More resources(Threads) necessary

Comment: could you explain this behavior ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. i did "*The Task Scheduler sees no need to allocate any more (or different) resources for you*" this is about the time you need to read up on tasks and the thread pool. I suggest blogs by Stephen Toub, and Stephen Cleary

Answer (score 1):

your 2 functions have not the same delay

the first have a variable delay (1, 2 and 3 sec), and the second have constant delay (2 sec)

if you write

```
await Task.Delay(2000); //instead of await Task.Delay(1000 * delay);
```

you will have the same result than the second function

The threadid is not really an incremental value, when a thread is finished, its "id" becomes available

The same threadID is a different task in your case